# Are there any hosting providers or cloud computing providers providing services with IPv6?

Tags: ipv6, cloud-hosting

You hear a lot of talk about IPv6, but I have yet to see it in the wild. Are there any hosting providers or cloud computing providers that offer services that use IPv6?

I'm not looking for something like the Hurricane Electric tunnel broker. I'd like to run a server somewhere with a publicly routable IPv6 address!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be quite a few

- http://vr.org/
- http://www.fix6.net/ipv6-webhosting/ -- A large list of mainly Dutch hosting providers.
- http://www.verio.com/web-hosting/ipv6-hosting/

And many more. If you look, there is probably one in your country somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Linode offers IPv6 VPS's - http://www.linode.com/IPv6/